# Multiple IP configuration on multiple NIC on same server

Tags: linux, centos

In my server I have two NICs(say eth0 & eth1). I configure separate IP for both NIC in centOS 6.3, like below:
**ifcfg-eth0**

```
    TYPE=Ethernet
    BOOTPROTO=none
    IPADDR=10.1.1.1
    PREFIX=27
    GATEWAY=10.1.1.10
    DNS1=10.1.1.11
    DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
    IPV6INIT=no
    NAME="Auto eth0"
    UUID=4aa88f11-51ed-46de-9c54-1dd2bbbf286a
    ONBOOT=yes
    HWADDR=1c:df:0f:1d:73:23
    LAST_CONNECT=1359432400
    NETMASK=X.X.X.X
    DEVICE=eth0
    USERCTL=no
```

**ifcfg-eth1**

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.1.1.2
PREFIX=28
GATEWAY=10.1.1.10
DNS1=10.1.1.11
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Auto eth1"
UUID=4aa88f11-51ed-46de-9c54-1dd2bbbf286a
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=1c:df:0f:1d:73:23
LAST_CONNECT=1359432400
NETMASK=X.X.X.X
DEVICE=eth1
USERCTL=no
```

Here, I am not able to ping both IP at a time. Only one is working.
Even, "ifconfig" is showing expected output.

Comment: you should have only one gateway, even if you have two NICs. Or you'll need a more complex configuration

Comment: what's the ip of the host you try to ping with? can it reach both the subnets?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong scenario. I am using same gateway. But only one IP is working at a time. If I do ifdown to working one, second starts working.

Comment: You have the same `HWADDR` on both of them. That will not work to have both on the same subnet. Only one device on a subnet can have a specific MAC address. Also, you have the same `UUID` but I'm not sure if that's critical to functionality - you should probably fix that, though, too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since CentOS/RHEL6 onwards (newer kernels) there was a change in rp_filter settings. For full explaination please follow this link:

http://z-issue.com/wp/linux-rhel-6-centos-6-two-nics-in-the-same-subnet-but-secondary-doesnt-ping/

In short, there are two options:

1) edit the file "/etc/sysctl.conf"

## change the value from 1 to 2 in the following line:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
```

## Add this line:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
```

After edit, it should look like this:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
```

reload the configuration by typing

```
sysctl -p
```

Now you should be able to ping both IPs

2) Second option is to use bonding but it may require your switch side config. I am writing sample configs here with 802.3ad loadbalancing mode interfaces eth1 and eth2

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.10.52
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.10.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
BONDING_OPTS="miimon=100 mode=4"
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0:0

```
DEVICE=bond0:0
USERCTL=no
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.10.53
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.10.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
BONDING_OPTS="miimon=100 mode=4"
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2

```
DEVICE=eth2
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set them up on a different subnets.  So you have to setup routing to route between the different networks.

Check your `netstat -nr` to see what your routing table looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong scenario. Actually both have same subnet. But only one IP is working at a time. If I do ifdown to working one, second starts working.

Comment: Okay, unless you team them you can't have two NICs on the same network on the same machine.